# Using loops in xarray.concat to select different time steps

Tags: python, loops, concatenation, python-xarray

I am new to python and I am looking for some help with a loop structure. specifically to use a loop structure to prevent a long function line. I created a Dataset with yearly seasonal precipitation data of Northern Europe. I am only interested in the summer data of the years 1950-2018

```
print (PrNEU)
    <xarray.DataArray 'rr' (time: 273, latitude: 201, longitude: 464)>

    Coordinates:
      * latitude   (latitude) float64 25.38 25.62 25.88 26.12 ... 74.88 75.12 75.38
      * longitude  (longitude) float64 -40.38 -40.12 -39.88 ... 74.88 75.12 75.38
      * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1950-06-01 1950-09-01 ... 2018-06-01
```

`NEW = xr.concat([PrNEU[0,:,:],PrNEU[4,:,:],PrNEU[8,:,:],dim='time')`

```
Print (NEW)
    <xarray.DataArray 'rr' (time: 3, latitude: 88, longitude: 200)>

    Coordinates:
      * longitude  (longitude) float64 -9.875 -9.625 -9.375 ... 39.38 39.62 39.88
      * latitude   (latitude) float64 49.62 49.88 50.12 50.38 ... 70.88 71.12 71.38
      * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1950-06-01 1951-06-01 1952-06-01
```

I can write down all the time steps by hand, but there have to be simpler ways to create a new data set with only the yearly summer data from 1950 - 2018

Any help with how to organize a loop would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is quite convenient to use `.sel` to do this:

```py
# selecting summer (June) every year
mon = PrNEU.time.dt.month == 6

NEW = PrNEU.sel(time=mon)
```

Then you can do some further analysis with the yearly summer data `NEW`.